# Where can I find a list of all reverse listings on European stock exchanges for a specific period?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, stock-markets, ipo, europe

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_takeover):

> A reverse takeover or reverse merger (reverse IPO) is the acquisition
>   of a public company by a private company so that the private company
>   can bypass the lengthy and complex process of going public. The
>   transaction typically requires reorganization of capitalization of the
>   acquiring company.

Is there a list of all reverse listings, by which I explicitly mean reverse mergers with the goal of utilizing/obtaining the the status of being a public listed company, for a specific period in a specific European country? What sources should I consult?

I googled for news articles on reverse listings/reverse IPO's and reverse take-overs, but I don't think this will be sufficient.

Comment: (For the US market I can find some decent sources)

Comment: Are news articles not sufficient because they don't provide the information you're looking for? What lists did you find for US markets?

Comment: No I meant that I'd guess just googling for new articles will only give me some of the reverse take-overs, and I'd still be far from having a complete (or even decent) list. For example for the Netherlands I found only 9 reverse listings through news articles.
US:
http://ibkb.interactivebrokers.com/node/1721
http://investorshub.advfn.com/boards/read_msg.aspx?message_id=19737681

And I know a list can be obtained through: SDC for example
http://www.library.hbs.edu/go/sdcplatinum.html

Comment: Furthermore using scholar.google I found some articles on reverse listings. In these articles the authors do hint on where they obtained their data. But again, these studies are generally focused on the US markets.
(Btw: thanks for the edit)

Answer (score 1):

I found the zephyr database, which does the job. Nonetheless if someone knows other (open) sources, be welcome to answer.